# How to handle cost value fluctuations when training a neural network from scratch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, mnist

I have been learning the calculus behind neural networks and have attempted to implement it using the MNIST database. However, I am encountering challenges with fluctuating cost values, even after experimenting with various learning rates. In an attempt to debug, I inserted print statements to check if changes were occurring with the weights matrix and if different results are being obtained, and indeed, they were. I initially initialized the weights normally and did not normalize the image values. Subsequently, I normalized them and initialized the weights using the Xavier/Glorot initialization. The cost function employed here is the Mean Squared Error. Despite these adjustments, I find myself stuck and seeking guidance.

```
import numpy as np

class Layer:
    def __init__(self, m, n, activation):
        self.input = m
        self.weights = np.random.rand(m.shape[1], n) * np.sqrt(2 / (m.shape[1] + n))
        self.bias = np.zeros((1, n))
        self.activation = activation.lower()
        self.res = self.getValues()

    def apply_activation(self, values):
        if self.activation == 'relu':
            return np.maximum(0, values)
        elif self.activation == 'sigmoid':
            return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-values))
        elif self.activation == 'softmax':
            exp_values = np.exp(values - np.max(values, axis=-1, keepdims=True))
            return exp_values / np.sum(exp_values, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
        else:
            return values

    def getValues(self):
        vals = np.dot(self.input, self.weights)
        neuron_vals = vals + self.bias
        return self.apply_activation(np.array(neuron_vals))

    def update(self, learningRate, n_vals, grad):
        self.weights -= learningRate * np.dot(n_vals.T, grad)
        self.bias -= learningRate * grad
```

The above code snippet initializes the layers

```
class Model:
    def __init__(self, learningRate=0.01):
        self.epoch = 0
        self.al = learningRate
        self.inpLay = None
        self.hidLay_1 = None
        self.hidLay_2 = None
        self.outLay = None
        self.initiateLayers()

    @staticmethod
    def flat(img):
        img = np.array(img) / 255
        return np.matrix(np.concatenate(img).flatten())

    @staticmethod
    def softmax_derivative(z):
        s = z.reshape(-1, z.shape[-1])
        exp_values = np.exp(s - np.max(s, axis=-1, keepdims=True))
        softmax_output = exp_values / np.sum(exp_values, axis=-1, keepdims=True)

        jacobian_matrix = np.diagflat(softmax_output) - np.einsum('ij,ik->ijk', softmax_output, softmax_output)

        return np.sum(jacobian_matrix, axis=-1)

    def initiateLayers(self):
        img = x_train[self.epoch]
        self.inpLay = self.flat(img)
        self.hidLay_1 = Layer(self.inpLay, 16, "Sigmoid")
        self.hidLay_2 = Layer(self.hidLay_1.res, 16, "Sigmoid")
        self.outLay = Layer(self.hidLay_2.res, 10, "SoftMax")
        self.epoch += 1

    def costFunc(self, output, label):
        cost = np.sum(np.square((output - label)))
        J_wb = cost / 2
        return J_wb

    def gd_OH(self, n_vals, label):
        softmax_del = self.softmax_derivative(n_vals)
        return np.multiply((n_vals - label), softmax_del)

    def gd(self, n_vals, grad, w):
        return np.multiply(np.dot(w, grad.T).T, (n_vals * (1 - n_vals)))

    def feedForward(self, img):
        self.inpLay = self.flat(img)
        self.hidLay_1.input = self.inpLay
        self.hidLay_2.input = self.hidLay_1.res
        self.outLay.input = self.hidLay_2.res
        return self.outLay.getValues()

    def backPropagation(self, label):
        grad = self.gd_OH(self.outLay.res, label)
        self.outLay.update(self.al, self.hidLay_2.res, grad)
        grad_2 = self.gd(self.hidLay_2.res, grad, self.outLay.weights)
        self.hidLay_2.update(self.al, self.hidLay_1.res, grad_2)
        grad_3 = self.gd(self.hidLay_1.res, grad_2, self.hidLay_2.weights)
        self.hidLay_1.update(self.al, self.inpLay, grad_3)

    def train(self):
        label = y_train[self.epoch - 1]
        out = self.outLay.res
        while True:
            labels = np.zeros(10)
            labels[label] += 1
            labels = np.matrix(labels)
            cost = self.costFunc(out, labels)
            print(f"Epoch: {self.epoch} :: Cost: {cost}")
            self.backPropagation(labels)
            if self.epoch == 100:
                break
            img, label = x_train[self.epoch], y_train[self.epoch]
            out = self.feedForward(img)
            self.epoch += 1

    def predict(self, img):
        return self.feedForward(img)
```

The above code defines the model.

```
nn = Model()
nn.train()

import random

r = random.randint(0, len(x_test))
testImg, testLabel = x_test[r], y_test[r]
prediction = nn.predict(testImg)

print(prediction, testLabel)
```

The provided code initializes a model object, allowing for training and testing.

[The Cost Values over the epochs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0LmE.png)
reveals a consistent pattern without improvement, even after running the code for approximately 10,000 epochs.

What modifications can be implemented to enhance the model's performance?

Observing cost fluctuations from the initial epochs, I attempted to find solutions on online forums and consulted Michael Nielsen's Neural Network book without success.
I used ChatGPT as well, as a final measure, but the solutions provided by it was repetitive and did not address the issue, even after implementing suggested changes.
I cross-checked the mathematics alongside the code and everything appeared to be in order.
I considered the possibility that the weight initialization using the Xavier/Glorot method might be causing problems, but even after removing it, the issue persisted. I am struggling to identify the root cause.